# Network Time Protocol vs Real Time Clock

Tags: networking, time, protocols, clock

After doing some research related to the Network Time Protocol (NTP), I was wondering what could be a real use of it. From my knowledge, almost all devices have a real time clock that keeps updating itself even when the machine is shutted down. Then, when the machine boots up, the software clock takes its value from this hardware clock (the real time clock).

What is the point of taking the time from a server and, therefore, exposing the machine to some kind of time attack? Is the goal to keep a set of hosts strictly synchronized and avoid that their times differ too much (but how much could be, in reality, this "too much"? ) ? Also: if a host configures NTP, does it still have an initialized software clock from the real time clock that simply corrects itself according to the received NTP packets, or not?

Comment: The Real Time Clock is not very accurate.

Comment: You maybe don't realize just how wrong computers' clocks can get. One common case is a computer with a dead PRAM battery, which will start up thinking it is 1980-01-01T00:00:00.  Drift of multiple seconds per day while running is also very common.  Disagreement of just _one_ second between client and server can be enough to cause problems, depending on the protocol.

Comment: So, how do common PCs keep the time? I don't see any NTP process running on my computer.

Comment: @zwol: some example of such protocols?

Comment: One example is any network file protocol, with some task executing on the clients that depends on file modification timestamps being consistent, such as a build farm.